# calling ERC20 function from ERC721 throws an error

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I am calling ERC20.transfer inside of ERC721 contract.
I have no problem in compiling and migrating it, but when that line of code is executed, metamask is throwing an error.

Here is my code:

The line causing the error: Erc20Contract.transfer(nftInfo[from].creator, 10)

ERC721

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "./ERC20Token.sol";

contract NFTtoken is ERC721 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    ERC20Token Erc20Contract;

    constructor(address tokenAddress) ERC721("NC NFT example", "NCNFT") {
        owner = msg.sender;
        decimals = 0;
        Erc20Contract = ERC20Token(tokenAddress);
    }
    function transferNFT(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)  public returns (bool){
        transferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
        Erc20Contract.transfer(nftInfo[from].creator, 10);
        //^^^^^^^^^ this line is causing an errror. 
    }
}
```

ERC20

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract ERC20Token is IERC20 {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 tokens) public override returns (bool) {
        balances[msg.sender] = SafeMath.sub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = SafeMath.sub(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
const NFTtoken = artifacts.require("NFTtoken");
const ERC20token = artifacts.require("ERC20Token")
let _totalSupply = 20000;

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(ERC20token, _totalSupply, web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether'), [web3.utils.asciiToHex('Rama'), web3.utils.asciiToHex('Nick'), web3.utils.asciiToHex('Jose')]); 
    deployer.deploy(NFTtoken, ERC20token.address);
};
```

error:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] 
while formatting outputs from RPC 
'{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
"code":-32000,"data": {"0x18abb17dda4df83e94eb19c0db814e9d4d3ec65a5f96001c0597fb9e93f1a816":{"error":"revert","program_counter":4807,"return":"0x"},
"stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transacti
on: revert\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\utils\\runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)","name":"RuntimeError"}}}}' {code: -32603, message: `[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{…/task_queues.js:93:5)","name":"RuntimeError"}}}}'`}

Uncaught (in promise) {code: -32603, message: `[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{…/task_queues.js:93:5)","name":"RuntimeError"}}}}'`, 
stack: '{\n  "code": -32603,\n  "message": "[ethjs-query] wh…gaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:1:216902)'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `NFTtoken` has enough balance of your `ERC20` token (as you are transferring 10 tokens from the NFT contract to the NFT creator), I would say your implementation of the `transfer` method on the ERC20 contract is not correct.

As you are transferring tokens to the `to` address you should `add` the amount to the `to` balance instead of substracting it:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract ERC20Token is IERC20 {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 tokens) public override returns (bool) {
        balances[msg.sender] = SafeMath.sub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = SafeMath.add(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard,  that wasn't the cause of the error, but nice catch! Thank you for your comment.